# Instances are not healthy on the target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have following to create a autoscaling group and attach to the Application Load-balancer. Configured a nat gateway to route traffic to download required httpd service. But still instances are terminated on the target group.
I thought that something to do with the Nat gateway, may be it can't download httpd and health check failed, but I can see correct route attachment.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: ec2-instance
  
Parameters:
  # Azs:
  #   Description: Avialbility zones
  #   Type: String
  #   Default: ap-southeast-2a

  AMIs:
    Description: AMIs
    Type: String
    Default: Linux
    AllowedValues:
      - Linux
      - Windows
  
  InstanceCount:
    Description: Number of instances
    Type: Number
    Default: 1

  Environment:
    Description: Hosting Environment
    Type: String
    Default: Dev
    AllowedValues:
      - Dev
      - Prod

  Subnet01:
    Description: Subnet1
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.1.0/24

  Subnet02:
    Description: Subnet2
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.2.0/24
    
  LaunchTemplateVersionNumber:
    Default: 1
    Type: String
# Metadata:
  
Mappings:
  FreeTier:
    Linux:
      HVM64: ami-0d9f286195031c3d9
    Windows:
      HVM64: ami-09cf24ffd6d332930

Conditions:
  SelectImage: !Equals [!Ref AMIs, Linux]
  SelectEnv: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, Dev]
  
# Transform:
  
Resources:
  
  ApplicationLB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: application
      IpAddressType: "ipv4"
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
        - !Ref MySubnet01
        - !Ref MySubnet02
      Name: WebAppLB
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled
          Value: true
        # - Key: access_logs.s3.prefix
        #   Value: lb-logs
        # - Key: access_logs.s3.enabled
        #   Value: true
        # - Key: access_logs.s3.bucket
        #   Value: 990123

      SecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref SecurityALB
        - !Ref enbalessh
       
  ALBListner:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLB
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
      Port: 80
      Protocol: "HTTP"
  
  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 60
      HealthCheckPath: /index.html
      HealthCheckPort: "traffic-port"
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 40
      HealthCheckProtocol: "HTTP"
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
      TargetType: "instance"
      Matcher: 
        HttpCode: "200"
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: load_balancing.algorithm.type
          Value: round_robin
        - Key: "deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds"
          Value: "300"
        

  MyVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true

  MySubnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
          - 0
          - Fn::GetAZs:
              Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet01
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
  
  MySubnet02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
          - 1
          - Fn::GetAZs:
              Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet02 
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
  

  MyRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc

  MyIgw:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  
  Subnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable

  Subnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable
  
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref MyIgw
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc

  MyEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment

  MyNAT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties: 
      AllocationId: !GetAtt MyEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet02
  
  RouteToNat:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: MyIgw
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref MyNAT  


  Launchtemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: !If [SelectImage, !FindInMap [ FreeTier, Linux, HVM64 ], !FindInMap [ FreeTier, Windows, HVM64 ]]  
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: cfn-putty
        UserData: 
          Fn::Base64: |
            #!/bin/bash
            sudo yum -y install httpd
            sudo touch /var/www/html/index.html
            echo "webserver v1" > /var/www/html/index.html
            sudo hostname >> /var/www/html/index.html
            sudo ifconfig >> /var/www/html/index.html
            systemctl start httpd.service    
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt enbalessh.GroupId
          - !GetAtt SecurityALB.GroupId


  LauncConfig:
    Type:  AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    DependsOn:
      -  RouteToNat
    Properties:
      DefaultInstanceWarmup: 60
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 120
      HealthCheckType: ELB
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref MySubnet01
        - !Ref MySubnet02
      MaxSize: 3
      MinSize: 1
      TargetGroupARNs: 
        - !Ref  MyTargetGroup
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref InstanceCount
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref Launchtemplate
        Version: !Ref LaunchTemplateVersionNumber
      Tags:
        - Key: "Environment"
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: !If [SelectEnv,Dev,Prod]
        - Key: "Name"
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: !Sub 
            - "web-${os}-${env}"
            - os: !Ref AMIs
              env: !Ref Environment
                     
              
  enbalessh:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: enable-ssh
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"  
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc  

  SecurityALB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Incoming-traffic-lb
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because you are just creating two **private subnets** and nothing else. So your instances, can't access the internet to setup `httpd` and they fail.

I modified your template to create **public** subnets instead (you can extend the template to create 2 public and 2 private subnets later if you want, using the corrected template as a foundation block). The following template **works** (I deployed it to check):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: ec2-instance

Parameters:
  # Azs:
  #   Description: Avialbility zones
  #   Type: String
  #   Default: ap-southeast-2a

  AMIs:
    Description: AMIs
    Type: String
    Default: Linux
    AllowedValues:
      - Linux
      - Windows

  InstanceCount:
    Description: Number of instances
    Type: Number
    Default: 1

  Environment:
    Description: Hosting Environment
    Type: String
    Default: Dev
    AllowedValues:
      - Dev
      - Prod

  Subnet01:
    Description: Subnet1
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.1.0/24

  Subnet02:
    Description: Subnet2
    Type: String
    Default: 10.0.2.0/24

  LaunchTemplateVersionNumber:
    Default: 1
    Type: String
# Metadata:

Mappings:
  FreeTier:
    Linux:
      HVM64: ami-0d9f286195031c3d9
    Windows:
      HVM64: ami-09cf24ffd6d332930

Conditions:
  SelectImage: !Equals [!Ref AMIs, Linux]
  SelectEnv: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, Dev]

# Transform:

Resources:

  ApplicationLB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: application
      IpAddressType: "ipv4"
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
        - !Ref MySubnet01
        - !Ref MySubnet02
      Name: WebAppLB
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled
          Value: true
        # - Key: access_logs.s3.prefix
        #   Value: lb-logs
        # - Key: access_logs.s3.enabled
        #   Value: true
        # - Key: access_logs.s3.bucket
        #   Value: 990123

      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SecurityALB
        - !Ref enbalessh

  ALBListner:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref ApplicationLB
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
      Port: 80
      Protocol: "HTTP"

  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 60
      HealthCheckPath: /index.html
      HealthCheckPort: "traffic-port"
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 40
      HealthCheckProtocol: "HTTP"
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
      TargetType: "instance"
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: "200"
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: load_balancing.algorithm.type
          Value: round_robin
        - Key: "deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds"
          Value: "300"


  MyVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true

  MySubnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
          - 0
          - Fn::GetAZs:
              Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet01
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc

  MySubnet02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
          - 1
          - Fn::GetAZs:
              Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet02
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc


  MyRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc

  MyIgw:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  Subnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable

  Subnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable

  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref MyIgw
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc

  # MyEIP:
  #   Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
  #   DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
  #
  # MyNAT:
  #   Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
  #   Properties:
  #     AllocationId: !GetAtt MyEIP.AllocationId
  #     SubnetId: !Ref MySubnet02
  #
  # RouteToNat:
  #   Type: AWS::EC2::Route
  #   DependsOn: MyIgw
  #   Properties:
  #     RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable
  #     DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  #     NatGatewayId: !Ref MyNAT

  RouteToIgw:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: MyIgw
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref MyIgw


  Launchtemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: !If [SelectImage, !FindInMap [ FreeTier, Linux, HVM64 ], !FindInMap [ FreeTier, Windows, HVM64 ]]
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: cfn-putty
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64: |
            #!/bin/bash
            sudo yum -y install httpd
            sudo touch /var/www/html/index.html
            echo "webserver v1" > /var/www/html/index.html
            sudo hostname >> /var/www/html/index.html
            sudo ifconfig >> /var/www/html/index.html
            systemctl start httpd.service
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt enbalessh.GroupId
          - !GetAtt SecurityALB.GroupId


  LauncConfig:
    Type:  AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    DependsOn:
      -  RouteToIgw
    Properties:
      DefaultInstanceWarmup: 60
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 120
      HealthCheckType: ELB
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref MySubnet01
        - !Ref MySubnet02
      MaxSize: 3
      MinSize: 1
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !Ref  MyTargetGroup
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref InstanceCount
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref Launchtemplate
        Version: !Ref LaunchTemplateVersionNumber
      Tags:
        - Key: "Environment"
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: !If [SelectEnv,Dev,Prod]
        - Key: "Name"
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
          Value: !Sub
            - "web-${os}-${env}"
            - os: !Ref AMIs
              env: !Ref Environment


  enbalessh:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: enable-ssh
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc

  SecurityALB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Incoming-traffic-lb
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
      VpcId: !Ref MyVpc
```

Comment: Why it didn't go through EIP ? and it has a route to Nat gateway. 0.0.0.0 from private subnets going to internet via Nat gateway. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I was using NAT gateway on private subnet. Thats why it can't get through EIP.